# How to sort may data from largest to smallest using Python

Tags: python

So i have this code, i want to sort out the values of v from largest to smallest.

```
from itertools import product
from collections import Counter
from random import choice
import itertools
import random
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as random
import pandas as pd
import collections


y = []
for x in [(choice([i for i in range(1,10) if i not in [2]])) for j in range(5)]:
    y.append(x)
a = collections.Counter(y)
for k,v in a.items():
    b = sorted(v)
    print(b)
```

I tried to used sorted but i got an error like this one: "ypeError: 'int' object is not iterable"

Comment: `k` is the key, you can't sort on, can you give an example ? When iterating k is the key and v the value for {7: 2, 6: 2, 8: 1} (example) none of these digits is sortable alone, what do you expect ?

Comment: Nice! I edit it, I want to sort out the value of v

Answer (score 3):

Sort the values like this:

```
In [1066]: {k: v for k, v in sorted(a.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])}                                                                                                                                   
Out[1066]: {3: 1, 4: 1, 1: 1, 6: 1, 9: 1}
```

#### OR if you just want a list of sorted values, you can simply do this:

```
sorted(a.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a.sort(reverse=True)
>>> a
[3, 2, 1]
```